# Is there any way to open a folder(as a file)?

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, disk

I am reading about OS. I have read that directories are implemented as a file which contains information about the relevant files and sub-directories. I am just curious to open it and see the file.I guess by theory it is considered as a part of file system rather than a file so it might be difficult. Is it possible open those files(folders)?

Answer (score 0):

File sytems normally provide users with opendir and readdir syscalls to open/read directories if that's what you're looking for. Normal open/close syscall are only intended for files.